# updating rows using python

Tags: python-3.x, updating

so here i want to write a python code to update a table. Like i have created a table called customers with some columns. and i want to update the column getting input from user and if the user does not give any input i want it to take its previous value itself. please help me with it i am new to python.

```
dummy=[]
user_input=int(input("Enter the identification number you want to change:"))
First_name=input("Enter the First name:")
if len(First_name)!=0:
    dummy+="Firstname="+First_name
    cursor.execute("update customer4 set Firstname=? where identification=?")
    values=(dummy,user_input)
    conn.commit

Last_name=input("Enter the last name:")
if len(Last_name)!=0:
    if len(First_name)!=0:
        dummy+="Firstname"+First_name, "Lastname"+Last_name
        cursor.execute("update customer4 set Firstname=?, Lastname=? where identification=?")
        values=(dummy,user_input)
        conn.commit
     else:
         dummy+="Lastname"+Last_name
         cursor.execute("update customer4 set Lastname=? where identification=?")
         values=(dummy,user_input)
         conn.commit

         print(cursor.rowcount,"record affected")
```

and this is my python code. help me with it as i am learning python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your execute() lines is wrong. Using "?" as a placehoder is the right way to go but your values need to be inserted like this:

```
cursor.execute("update customer4 set Firstname=? where identification=?", (dummy,user_input))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user_input=int(input("Enter the identification number you want to change:"))
        query = "SELECT identification FROM CUSTOMER4 WHERE identification=?"
        cursor.execute(query, (user_input,))
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        if len(data) == 0:
            print("Does not exist")

        else:
            print("Enter the first name:")
            a=input()
            print("Enter the last name:")
            b=input()
            print("Enter the email id:")
            c=input()
            print("Enter phone no:")
            d=input()
            if len(a)==0:
                a=("SELECT Firstname from CUSTOMER4 where identification=?",user_input)
                conn.commit()
            if len(b)==0:
                b=("SELECT Lastname from CUSTOMER4 where identification=?",user_input)
                conn.commit()
            if len(c)==0:
                c=("SELECT Email from CUSTOMER4 where identification=?",user_input)
                conn.commit()
            if len(d)==0:
                d=("SELECT Phoneno CUSTOMER4 where identification=?",user_input)
                conn.commit()
            else:
                query1=("UPDATE CUSTOMER4 set Firstname=?,Lastname=?,Email=?,Phoneno=?) where identification=?")
                values=(a,b,c,d,user_input)
                cursor.execute(query1, (values,))
                conn.commit()



        print(cursor.rowcount,"record affected")
```

i changed my code like this..its executing but not updating.where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

query1=("UPDATE CUSTOMER4 set Firstname=?,Lastname=?,Email=?,Phoneno=?) where identification=?")

parentheses())

You have closed two times.
Delete that closing parentheses")" after that Phoneno=?)